# Are the following two recursive sorting methods the same?

Tags: java, sorting, recursion

I've been working on selection sort and bubble sort using recursion. I've finally come up with two methods, and they worked perfectly fine. But as I took a final look at those, they look like just one one method which is `selectionSortRecursive`.  Could you tell me the difference (or are they the same)?

```
public static void selectionSortRecursive(Comparable[] list, int n)
{
    Comparable temp;
    if ( n > 1 ){

        for ( int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++ )
        {
            if(list[i].compareTo(list[i + 1]) > 0){
                temp = list[i];
                list[i] = list[i + 1];
                list[i + 1] = temp;
            }
        }

            selectionSortRecursive(list, n - 1);
       }
 }
```

```
public static void bubbleSortRecursive( Comparable[] list, int n) 
{
    Comparable tmp;
    if (n >1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
        {
            if(list[i+1].compareTo(list[i]) < 0)
            {
                tmp = list[i];
                list[i] = list[i+1]; 
                list[i+1] = tmp;
            }
        }
        bubbleSortRecursive( list, n - 1);
    }

}
```

Comment: Why not you simply write a main test and try them?

Comment: I tested them. they both worked perfectly. But now I can not tell if they are two different algorithms?

Comment: my question is are they two different algorithms which are selection and bubble sort? or they are just one algorithm?

Comment: Bubble sort and selection sort are two different algorithms, but the two methods you have seem to be doing the same thing (just have different method names and one difference which is the same logically speaking).  Is this a homework assignment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only line which is different is

```
 if(list[i].compareTo(list[i + 1]) > 0){
```

and

```
 if(list[i+1].compareTo(list[i]) < 0)
```

and provided compareTo is implemented correctly this will do the same thing.

BTW the `if(n > 1)` check is redundant. And I would move `tmp` to the most inner scope you can.

Both sorts are bubble sorts. A bubble sort "bubbles" values to the top/right position.

A selection sort selects the lowest/highest value repeatedly, swap in the selected with the position it needs to place it. i.e. the swap would be outside the loop to find the lowest/highest.

Answer (score 0):

It's both bubble sort, one bubbles the element from the top to the bottom, the other one does it the way round. Selection sort is different: it searches the smallest elements of all remaining (unsorted) elements and places it in the next slot, it does not change any other elements. Bubble sort, instead, always compares tow elements and swaps them is the first one is bigger (or smaller) than the second one - which is what you are doing.